# PHP / MySQL Query: Show results based on 2 conflicting conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is: show updates in a timeline.

The results should show updates from **January - December**, but at the same time list these months down **based on their year**.

A visual layout example for this is:

- January 2011
- February 2011
- May 2011
- June 2011
- July 2011
- September 2011
- November 2011
- December 2011
- **January 2012**
- **February 2012**

So on and so forth...

As you can see, it came back to January when the year 2011 was done.
What I am having trouble with my query is...

I am only able to order my results this way:

- January 2011
- **January 2012**
- February 2011
- **February 2012**
- May 2011
- June 2011
- July 2011
- September 2011
- November 2011
- December 2011

```php
$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM updates ORDER BY year ASC) AS the_id ORDER BY month ASC";
```

I am not sure how to query this correctly. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try this - ORDER BY `year`, `month` . Hope this will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM updates ORDER BY `year` ASC, `month` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple expressions in the ORDER BY clause, like this:

```
... ORDER BY `year`, `month`
```

-or-

Normally, date information is stored in a DATE or DATETIME column. In that case, you can order by the date column:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecol,'%M %Y') AS month_year
  FROM ...
 ORDER BY datecol
```

Or, you could derive an expression that has a value you can order by:

```
... ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`,' ',`month_name`),'%Y %M')
```